# Get Amazon SES Reporting in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How we get Amazon SES Reporting in codeigniter php ?
 I am use this code but cant work in codeigniter

```
<?php
    $client = SesClient::factory(array(
        'version'=> 'latest',     
        'region' => REGION
    ));

    try {
         $result = $client->getSendStatistics([]);
         echo($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
    }

    ?>
```

and follow this link 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-usage-statistics-api.html
But how it work in codeigniter?

Comment: i have still same problem.

Comment: i have still same problem